# How to read from JSON object array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an **html code** as shown below. The following html code displays **list of checkboxes** as shown in the screenshot below the code.

```
 <?php      
        $output['toggle_multi_tiles']=$_POST['toggle_multi_tiles'];  

        $output['episode_status']=$_POST['episode_status'];

        $fp = fopen('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
        fclose($fp);
        logActivity();

        if(file_exists('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json')){
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json'));
        }
 ?>

 <?php if($data){
 ?>
    <fieldset style="background-color:darkseagreen;">
       <input type="checkbox" id="ptp" value="0" name="toggle_multi_tiles[]" <?php if($data->{"toggle_multi_tiles[]"}==0){echo
          'checked';}?>>
       <label for="toggle-multi-off">PTP</label>
       <input type="checkbox" id="l'e" value="1" name="toggle_multi_tiles[]" <?php if($data->{"toggle_multi_tiles[]"}==1){echo
          'checked';}?>>
       <label for="position-one">L'E</label>
       <div>
          <button type="submit">Save</button>   //Line A
       </div>
    </fieldset>
<?php }  ?>
```

[image]

On hitting save button at Line A after selecting the first 2 check-boxes from the screenshot above , everything get save in JSON as shown below:

`{"toggle_multi_tiles":["0","1"]}`

**Problem Statement:**

The issue which I am having right now is after saving the 2 check-boxes, the only check-box which display on page refresh is the 1st one (**not both**).

`($data->{"toggle_multi_tiles[]"}==0)` from the html code is reading from JSON.

`($data->{"toggle_multi_tiles[]"}==1)` from the html code is reading from JSON.

[image]

Comment: What do you think `$data->{"toggle_multi_tiles[]"}==1` does?

Comment: Check the problem statement. It reads from JSON.

Comment: I would like you to explain the logic of this statement. It does not read JSON. It compares a property of an object to an integer `1`. Rubber duck debugging is usually a very good method.

Comment: Where do you see the values `{"toggle_multi_tiles":["0","1"]}`? In browser's console or in PHP?

Comment: On page refresh, why only first checkbox remains selected ? Why not both (1st and 2nd) ?

Comment: I see those values in php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197308/discussion-between-dharman-and-flash).

Comment: I have a file called landing.json

Comment: Your JSON object contains the key `toggle_multi_tiles`, but you're looking for the key `toggle_multi_tiles[]`. There's no `[]` in the key.

Comment: And the value of that property is an array, not a single number.

Comment: @barmar which property ?

Comment: In `{"toggle_multi_tiles":["0","1"]}` `["0", "1"]` is an array.

Comment: Why are you reading from the JSON file when you just wrote to it from a variable? Why not just `$data = $output;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key in your object is `toggle_multi_tiles`, not `toggle_multi_tiles[]`, so `$data->{"toggle_multi_tiles[]"}` should be `$data->toggle_multi_tiles`.

The value of this property is an array of strings, you can use `in_array()` to test whether a value is in it.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ptp" value="0" name="toggle_multi_tiles[]" <?php if(in_array("0", $data->toggle_multi_tiles)){echo
  'checked';}?>>
<label for="toggle-multi-off">PTP</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="l'e" value="1" name="toggle_multi_tiles[]" <?php if(in_array("1", $data->toggle_multi_tiles)){echo
  'checked';}?>>
```

Comment: That won't work. Only the values of the checked boxes are sent, so they won't be in specific indexes in the array.

Comment: If you only check box 1, the array will be `["1"]`.

Comment: Actually its working. But I wanted to check if its the correct approach.

Comment: It's not the correct approach, I doubt it's really working in all cases.

Comment: You are right. Its not working in all case. Whereas your code is working in all cases.